# Implementation of Facebook Connect - login/logout buttons

Tags: jquery, facebook, authentication, onclick, facebook-javascript-sdk

First time implementing Facebook login for me, and I can't get it to work properly.

I'm implementing Facebook Javascript SDK, and what I've done is to place the js code provided in Facebooks guide in a separate js-file, to prevent my index.html file to become messy, which seems to work fine.

**However, I have two problems I need help with:**

1. The code below, which trigger the login() and logout() functions (depending if the user is logged in or not) gives me an ugly generic button. I want Facebook's own button. How can I use this?
2. When being logged out and clicking the login button, the login popup opens up two times instead of one. The reason for this is that the js file (facebook.js) get's loaded two times, (by some reason) which means the click event is binded twice. How do I prevent this from happening?

I needed to write the code below myself because I couldn't find anything in Facebook's guide regarding this. If there is, where can I find it?

```
function showLoginButton() {
      $('#FBButton').html('Log in Facebook');
      $('#FBButton').on('click', function(){
          login();
      });
    }

function showLogoutButton() {
  $('#FBButton').html('Log out Facebook');
  $('#FBButton').on('click', function(){
      logout();
  });
}

showLoginButton();
showLogoutButton();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Facebook's own [login button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/) will solve your issues.

```
<div class="fb-login-button" autologoutlink="true" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200"
        data-max-rows="2" size="medium">
```

The button's text and functionality will automatically turn to 'Log Out' when user is connected and vice-versa.